# How to convert from LPCTSTR to LPSTR?

Tags: c++, windows, type-conversion

I have the following line of code:

```
LPSTR address = T2A((LPTSTR)hostAddress);
```

Can I convert LPCTSTR hostAddress to LPSTR **without using T2A** macros from "afxpriv.h"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro is defined in in AtlBase.h, use this h-file which is public and doesn't require any dependencies.

Correction: it is not defined directly in AtlBase.h, but it is enough to include AtlBase.h to use string conversion macros.