# C++ LPCTSTR to char*

Tags: c++, mfc, char, converters, lpcstr

I am using visual studio 2010 MFC to build a C++ program. My program calls a DLL that is not apart of the project and it accepts a char*. I have a function that gets a string in a format of LPCTSTR. I have been on google for about two hours now, and no solution found. How do I convert form a MFC LPCTSTR to a char*. Everything I have found either does not work, or just does not compile.

Comment: You are use unicode in project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MFC the easiest is to convert through `CStringA` (provided that resulting buffer will be a read-only argument):

```
LPCTSTR pszA = ...
CStringA sB(pszA);
const char* pszC = sB;
char* pszD = const_cast<char*>(pszC);
```

Other options are available and were discussed:

- [c++ convert from LPCTSTR to const char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587963/c-convert-from-lpctstr-to-const-char)
- [How to convert from LPCTSTR to LPSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510753/how-to-convert-from-lpctstr-to-lpstr)
- `WideCharToMultiByte`, `T2A` macros etc.

Comment: Don't use `CString`, ever, if avoidable.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with CString.  Works with ATL (without MFC) as well.

Comment: In MFC `CString` is the "native" string holder class, works perfectly. `std::string` is good also and has the advantage of being - since recently - a part of standard library. This question is clearly about `MFC` though.

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` is either defined as a `const wchar_t *` or a `const char *` depending on whether your project defined the preprocessor symbol `UNICODE` (or `_UNICODE`, I forget which one MFC uses).

So the solution to your problem depends on whether you're using the UNICODE setting or not.

If you are using it, you'll need to convert the string to a *narrow* string. Use [`CStringA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do this.

If you're not using UNICODE you'll need to make a copy that is mutable and pass it to the DLL, in case it wants to modify the string. You can do this by creating a copy using `CString`.

In either case, once you have a copy in a `CString` object then use the `GetBuffer` method to get a mutable pointer to the string, call the DLL function and then call `ReleaseBuffer` after the call.

Comment: Do not ever use CString if avoidable. Use `std::string` to make the copy.

Comment: @DeadMG Well don't use MFC if avoidable. And how do you get a `char *` from an `std::string`? There's nothing wrong with using MFC classes when playing in the MFC world.

Answer (score 1):

```
LPCTSTR patientName= L"";
CStringA sB(patientName);
const char* pszC = sB; 

DcmFileFormat fileformat;
//Type casting below to const char * str
OFCondition status = fileformat.loadFile(((LPCSTR)(CStringA)str));
if (status.good())
{
    if (fileformat.getDataset()->findAndGetString(DCM_PatientName, pszC).good())             
    {
        //Type casting from const char * to LPCTSTR
        m_List.InsertColumn(4, LPCTSTR(pszC) , LVCFMT_LEFT, 100); 
    }
 }
```

This was the way i used to typecast the variables