# C++: convert LPTSTR to char array

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, lptstr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert lptstr to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/convert-lptstr-to-char)

I need to convert an `LPTSTR p` to `CHAR ch[]`. I am new to C++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WIN32_IE 0x500
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Strsafe.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    string res;
    CString path;
    char ch[MAX_PATH];
    LPTSTR p = path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH);
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, p);

/* some operation with P and CH */

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    { /* succeeded */
        cout << ch;
    } /* succeeded */
    else
    { /* failed */
        cout << "error";
    } /* failed */
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342772/convert-lptstr-to-char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LPTSTR is a (non-const) TCHAR string. Depends if it is Unicode or not it appears. LPTSTR is char* if not Unicode, or w_char* if so.

If you are using non-Unicode strings LPTSTR is just a char*, otherwise do:

```
size_t size = wcstombs(NULL, p, 0);
char* CharStr = new char[size + 1];
wcstombs( CharStr, p, size + 1 );
```

Also, this link can help:

[Convert lptstr to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/342772/1065190)

Comment: I have Error 23 error C2664: 'wcstombs' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'LPTSTR' to 'const wchar_t *'

Comment: You have non-Unicode strings, you don't need to use wcstombs() in this case. Just use a simple cast to char*.

Comment: +1 `LPTSTR is char* if not Unicode, or w_char* if so.` It was a surprisingly long time until I ran across this little bit of clarity.  Quick, helpful summary of the same at http://www.kerwal.com/home/charwchartwchartcharomgwtftmi.

Answer (score 2):

First, you defined `char* ch[MAX_PATH]` instead of `char ch[MAX_PATH]`.

Regarding your question, LPTSTR (*Long Pointer to TCHAR String*) is equivalent to `LPWSTR` (which is `w_char*`) if it's unicode, or just LPSTR (`char*`) if it is not. You can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782106/c-lpctstr-to-char) for reference about conversion in each case.

**EDIT**: To cut to the chase, here's some code:

```
if (sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(char))  // String is non-unicode
    strcpy(ch, (char*)(p));       
else                                // String is unicode
    wcstombs(ch, p, MAX_PATH);
```

**EDIT 2**: In windows I would recommend using `TCHAR` instead of `char`. It will save you some headache.

**EDIT 3**: As a side note, if you want to prevent Visual Studio from flooding you with warnings about unsafe functions, you can add something like the following to the very beginning of your code:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
```

Comment: Can you write some code?

Comment: @Sasha the reference I gave you should have covered it, but sure. I added sample code to the answer.

Comment: I think ATL conversion helpers make the code easier. Moreover, if you want to do a check for Unicode vs. ANSI/MBCS builds, I'd prefer checking with the preprocessor _at compile-time_ with `UNICODE/_UNICODE` preprocessor macros (which are `#define`'d in Unicode builds), instead of checking at run-time with `if(sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(char)) ...`.

Comment: +1 for compile-time checking :)

Comment: Its usually best to try if the secure template overloads (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) silence enough warnings, instead of disabling the warnings altogether. After all there is a reason why these warnings exist.

Answer (score 2):

`LPTSTR` means `TCHAR*` (expanding those Win32 acronyms typedefs can make it easier to understand them). `TCHAR` expands to `char` in ANSI/MBCS builds, and to `wchar_t` in Unicode builds (which should be the default in these days for better internationalization support).

This table summarizes the **`TCHAR` expansions in ANSI/MBCS and Unicode builds**:

```
          |   ANSI/MBCS    |     Unicode
  --------+----------------+-----------------
  TCHAR   |     char       |     wchar_t
  LPTSTR  |     char*      |     wchar_t*
  LPCTSTR |  const char*   |  const wchar_t*
```

So, in ANSI/MBCS builds, `LPTSTR` expands to `char*`; in Unicode builds it expands to `wchar_t*`.

`char ch[MAX_PATH]` is an array of `char`'s in both ANSI and Unicode builds.

If you want to convert from a `TCHAR` string (`LPTSTR`) to an ANSI/MBCS string (`char`-based), you can use **[ATL string conversion helpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**, e.g.:

```
LPTSTR psz;   // TCHAR* pointing to something valid    
CT2A ch(psz); // convert from TCHAR string to char string
```

(Note also that in your original code you should call `CString::ReleaseBuffer()` which is the symmetric of `CString::GetBuffer()`.)

**Sample code** follows:

```
// Include ATL headers to use string conversion helpers
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
...

LPTSTR psz = path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH);
HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, psz);
path.ReleaseBuffer();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  // handle error
  ...
}

// Convert from TCHAR string (CString path) to char string.
CT2A ch(path);

// Use ch...
cout << static_cast<const char*>(ch) << endl;
```

Note also that **the conversion from Unicode to ANSI can be lossy**.