# In a swig .i file, how to resolve ms windows vc++ typedef type for 3rd party mfc based dll?

Tags: python, c++, dll, mfc, swig

I want to wrap a MFC C++ based SDK to a python module with swig. But here I think the problem involves C++ and swig only.

**Problem**

After compiling the .i file, when I started to build xxx_wrap.cxx, it raised an error.

`error C2182: 'arg1' : illegal use of type 'void'`

In cxx file, the error code is this `VOID arg1 ;`.

In original .h file the error code is a constructor function of a class `XXXxxx( VOID );`

**First Try**

I thought this was because swig took VOID as a complex structure. I changed the `VOID` in .h file to `void`. But after a 'successful' compiling, the python can not import the module. Because the function declaration is not the same as the one in the SDK DLL.

And the same problem happened in the `LPCSTR`.

`cannot convert from 'char **' to 'LPCSTR *'`

**PS**
I have added the `%include <windows.i>` into the .i files. But still the swig takes the `VOID` as a complex structure.

**Question**

How to write a right .i file for this kind of typedef? Is there any other wrapped code example? I have searched stackoverflow and github, but got nothing.

**Possible Solution**

Maybe I should write typedef in .i outside `%{ ... }%` section for swig other than just in .h file. But I don't know how. I am currently reading the swig doc for a third time.

**Restriction**

- The DLL files are provided as a device SDK, and I don't have the source files.
- From the .h files, we know that the DLL is based on multiple classes.

  ```
  class A;

  class B;

  class C;

  class __declspec(dllexport) D

  {
      ...

  private:    

      friend class A;

      friend class B;

      friend class C;

  }
  ```
- I have tried the ctypes before. The import was OK, but when I called a function, it raised an exception.

  `exception: access violation writing 0x1D1A9446`

  I think it is because this is a C++ mumber function. The code want to access a class member variant, which is out of the range of the function. That's why ctypes doesn't work for c++ class dll.

**SDK**

The SDK provides 15 .h files, 17 .dll files and 4 .lib fils. It supports both unicode and multi-byte code. It use a lot of LPCSTR and other string related typedefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is with `VOID`, need to see more code (such as, what is `VOID` defined as).

About `LPCSTR`, it is true that you can't convert. One way to do it would be to put what is explained on [C++ LPCTSTR to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782106/c-lpctstr-to-char) in a wrapper function in your .i. The fact that it is a `char**` indicates the C++ function will probably return a pointer to an internal string. Python doesn't know how to handle that so you should return a string instance. Example:

```
%inline %{
    std::string myFunc() // don't use char** since 
    {
         LPCTSTR pszA = ... create buffer for LPCSTR string
         callYourMFCFunc(& pszA);
         CStringA sB(pszA);
         return std::string((const char*)sB);
    }
%}
```

I haven't tested the above, it is my best guess based on that SO post so you might have to fix a bit but you get the idea. SWIG's `%inline` and `%extend` directives allow you to completely adapt one API to another (in this case, change a function that takes a char** as arg into a function that returns a string).